# Insert data in sqlitedatabase using AndroidStudio

Tags: android

I am trying to insert data in the table MyProduct but every time i run the program it shows "null pointer exception" in db.insertData() in MainActivity and method insertData() in MyHelper class. Can anyone please tell me whats going wrong?? Thank You

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MyHelper helper;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        helper=new MyHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=helper.getWritableDatabase();
        // helper.onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
        helper.insertData();
    }
}
```

**MyHelper.class**

```
public class MyHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    static final String DATABASE_NAME="MyDatabase";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    static final String TABLE_NAME="MyCatalog";
    static final String UID="ID";
    static final String UTITLE="TITLE";
    static final String UPRICE="PRICE";
    static final String UDESCP="DESCP";

    static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE"+TABLE_NAME+"("+UID+"VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY,"+UTITLE+ "  VARCHAR(255),"+UPRICE+"  VARCHAR(255),"+UDESCP+"  VARCHAR(255));";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE="DROP TABLE" +TABLE_NAME+"IF EXISTS";

    private Context context;

    public MyHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context=context;
        Message.message(context,"Constructor called");
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        Message.message(context,"on create");
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        Message.message(context,"table created");
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion,int newVersion) 
    {
        Message.message(context,"upgrade called");
        db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    ContentValues contentValues;
    public  SQLiteDatabase db;

    public void insertData()
    {
        contentValues.put(UID,"W");
        contentValues.put(UTITLE,"w");
        contentValues.put(UPRICE,"10");
        contentValues.put(UDESCP, "abc");
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't initialized your `db` or `contentValues` objects. At the start of your `insertData` method, try putting the following:

```
db = getWriteableDatabase();
contentValues = new ContentValues();
```